# In a typical MVC application, which layer is responsible for a Model->DTO conversion?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dto

In a standard Spring MVC application, where I have a Presentation layer, Controller layer, a Service layer, Repository/Persistence layer, which layer should be responsible for converting data retrieved from the DB to a DTO prior to sending to the presentation?

On one hand, I am thinking it should be at the Controller layer since it is specific to the data that is being required by the presentation, and is not "business logic" per se, however, on the other hand, I have nagging feeling that putting in intelligence (ie: knowing which fields to populate in the DTO) in the Controller is not really the job of the controller and should be relegated to the Service layer.

I realize that this may be a "gray" area, but is there a recommended practice?

Comment: That should be responsibility for the DAO, your Repository/Persistence layer. Based on that, this task is for Model.

Comment: Really?  In the repo layer?  That would mean that the DAO/Repo layer would need to have knowledge of data required at the presentation layer, which doesn't sound right.

Comment: The DAO layer needs to read data from the data source (in this case, the database) and convert this data in a structure that is known in other layers in the application, this is, the DTO. Then, the DTO passes from the DAO layer to your Service/business logic layer, where you will apply rules (if any) and then pass it to the Controller and, finally, to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly do not know of a recommended practice, but I can tell you how it has been done in the projects I've worked on so far.

The Data (let's say *Entity*) is retrieved from the DB is mapped onto a corresponding Java class in an *EntityMapper* class, which relies of course in the Repository layer, because it is a DAO operation.

Any business logic applied on it should be tackled in the Service Layer, which passes it to the Controller.

The controller must return the data, **but** if you do not want to retrieve all the DB data (e.g. IDs, unnecessary columns, etc) which are in your *Entity*, you can convert them to a server-client DTO, meaning that you can have a similar *EntityPresentation* (silly name, I know) class, but with fewer fields, that will be communicated by the Controller to the presentation layer.

Comment: That's kind of the way I was thinking as well.  There is nothing preventing me from using as doubble-duty my entity objects; just duplicate the necessary fields in a non-persisted entity copy.  I suspected that should be done at the Controller layer, but was not sure it truly belonged there.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not repository-related, and I think debatable whether it should go in the Controller or Service layer. I argue for Controller because it's related more to what you "respond" to the presentation layer than business-related.

Comment: @EricB. the task to do this duplication is not handled nor in Controller nor in Service but in an utility class, **but** is task of the Service layer to handle why is this data duplicated, probably due to some business logic rule.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Agreed that it belongs in a util class, but I'm still not convinced it should be delegated by the Service layer instead of the Controller.  Afterall, it is the role of the Controller that knows which part of the data the presentation needs.  Can you provide concrete examples why it should be the Service layer that delegates?

Comment: @EricB. the Controller will only pass the data prepared from the Service to the Presentation layer since the Service knows which rules to apply to the necessary data. I would ask you to show a scenario showing the Controller modifying the data instead of the Service.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Let's say you want the list of users in the presentation layer. The service/repository retrieves the list from the DB, but the objects are fully populated (pk, name, email, password, etc). From a Service perspective, it could be simply userService.findAll(). In the Controller there are 2 different methods (listUsersByName, listUsersByEmail). For the first one, you only need a DTO with users' id & name, and for the second, a DTO with id & email.  Why should the Service layer know that distinction?  Would seem to make more sense to do the DTO manipulation at the Controller level

Comment: @EricB. in the explained case, the fields to choose from the DTO are not defined nor in Service nor Controller, that logic belongs to the presentation itself.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Agreed, but you do not want to pass extra data to the presentation that is not required.  For both bandwidth (if the presentation layer is on the client side) and security purposes (ex: Flash presentation, Ajax presentation, etc).  So the Controller (or Service?) must limit the data being transferred.  The question is which one?